# Where is the "Exit Classic Experience" link in the Oslo layout?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, oslo

While using the Seattle Site layout, in lists or libraries, I find that at the very bottom of the left navigation, there is a link that says "Exit Classic Experience". I can't seem to find this link when using the Oslo layout since there is not a left navigation.

Does anyone know where this option is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “Exit classic experience” option displays in the left navigation. As you mentioned, the oslo is different with the seattle and the oslo does not have the left navigation.

To view this option, you need to use seattle or customize the master page to display the left navigation.

Another workaround with the oslo, you need to close the browser and re-open the list/library. It will switch back to the default experience.

Answer (score 2):

A blog I read had a trick to hide it that consisted of some javascript and css. I converted it to how to go back to modern from classic. Simply go to Console in your browser (normally F12), then write GoToModern(); in "console" (web console in Firefox). Thats all there is to it.